# Algebra Relational sql GROUP BY SORT BY ORDER BY

Tags: group-by, sql-order-by, relational-database, relational-algebra

I wanted to know what is the equivalent in GROUP BY, SORT BY and ORDER BY in algebra relational ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Neither is possible in relational algebra but people have been creating some "extensions" for these operations (Note: in the original text, part of the text is written as subscript).

GROUP BY, According to the book Fundamentals of Database Systems (Elmasri, Navathe 2011 6th ed):

> Another type of request that cannot be expressed in the basic relational algebra is to
> specify mathematical aggregate functions on collections of values from the database.
>
> ...
>
> We can define an AGGREGATE FUNCTION operation, using the symbol ℑ (pronounced
> script F)7, to specify these types of requests as follows:

> <grouping attributes> ℑ <function list> (R)

> where <grouping attributes> is a list of attributes of the relation specified in R, and <function list> is a list of (<function> <attribute>) pairs. In each such pair,
> <function> is one of the allowed functions—such as SUM, AVERAGE, MAXIMUM,
> MINIMUM,COUNT—and <attribute> is an attribute of the relation specified by R. The resulting relation has the grouping attributes plus one attribute for each element in the function list.

ORDER BY (SORT BY), [John L. Donaldson's lecture notes](http://web.archive.org/web/20120911095423/https://www.cs.oberlin.edu/%7Ejdonalds/311/lecture12.html).

> Since a relation is a set (or a bag), there is no ordering defined for a relation.  That is, two relations are the same if they contain the same tuples, irrespective of ordering.  However, a user frequently wants the output of a query to be listed in some particular order.  We can define an additional operator τ which sorts a relation if we are willing to allow an operator whose output is not a relation, but an ordered list of tuples.

> For example, the expression

> τLastName,FirstName(Student)

> generates a list of all the Student tuples, ordered by LastName (as the primary sort key) then FirstName (as a secondary sort key).  (The secondary sort key is used only if two tuples agree on the primary sort key.  A sorting operation can list any number of sort keys, from most significant to least significant.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use projection **π** for the columns that you want group the table by them without aggregating (The PROJECT operation removes any duplicate tuples)
as following:

**π c1,c2,c3 (R)**

where c1,c2,c3 are columns(attributes) and R is the table(the relation)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this SQL to relational algebra converter tool](http://www.grammaticalframework.org/qconv/qconv-a.html), we have:

```
SELECT agents.agent_code, agents.agent_name, SUM(orders.advance_amount)
FROM agents, orders
WHERE agents.agent_code = orders.agent_code
GROUP BY agents.agent_code, agents.agent_name
ORDER BY agents.agent_code
```

Written in functions sort of like:

```
τ agents.agent_code
 γ agent_code, agent_name, SUM(advance_amount)
  σ agents.agent_code = orders.agent_code (agents × orders)
```

With a diagram like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pec6d.png]